# Get single element from a List Java

Tags: java, list

[image]

I have above result list. I need to get one element or value from that list. How to achieve this.

```
public List<OriginTransactionsVM> findTransactionsOfOrigin(String origin_id) {

    List result=null;
    try {

        Query query = getSession().createSQLQuery("CALL getOriginTransactions(:string_acc_no)")
                .setParameter("string_acc_no", origin_id);
         result= query.list();

        // String rep =  (String) result.get(0);   need to achieve this result.get(0)[0] something like this

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Share code as well...

Comment: Is it an array of a list?

Comment: Please share the code showing how you have created the list and its data. It is required to post a correct answer instead making a guess.

Comment: I have shared the code. Please review the code and give a answer.

Comment: What you posted in your comment is right... result.get(0)[0] does the trick.

Comment: Or to make it clearer, you can set the cast list.get(0)  to an object array variable, and then retrieve the index you want.

Comment: No  its not working there is an error. "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to Object" this is the error when i do this

Comment: @HasiniNayanathara what's the error you are getting when you try `result.get(0)[0]`? did you try casting it?

Comment: Yes i tried. @Tomaz Fernandes have given the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you:

```
Object[] resultArray = (Object[]) result.get(0);
String rep = (String) resultArray[0];
```

Comment: Yah that's the answer. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can get the element at index by using,

```
list.get(index);
```

Comment: element comes as an array. That's the problem. Because i need to read a single value.

Comment: Then use array index to get that particular element example  : `list.get(index)[arrayindex]`

Comment: did you try `result.get(0).get(0)`

Comment: That is not possible